# Java static instance

Tags: java, static

So I just started my fist big project in Java and I'm following some tutorial but there is code that I dont understand at all.

```
package com.Legolando.Runa;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MODID, name = Reference.MODNAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class Runa {

@Mod.Instance
public static Runa instance = new Runa();
//  I dont get why instance of my class has to be static 

}
```

As you see I create an instance of this class inside this class (already cosmos for me) and this instance is static. Can someone explain what is a static instance? Is it the same as static variable or method?

Comment: Time to pick up a book on Java. You're not going to learn it very effectively by posting a question here for every keyword you come across.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to probably go through some basic tutorials before trying to write an actual project. And after that, you might need to reconsider your choice of first project. Writing a Minecraft mod using Forge is a quite complex first project, I would personally recommend to make a smaller stand-alone program. Regarding your actual question, I don't even think a @ Mod.Instance parameter needs to be static, it will probably work regardless. But you also don't even need to use @ Mod.Instance, since that is to get instances of other mods using their names. In this case, just use 'this'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code reminds me of Singleton Class in java.

```
public class Runa {

   private static Runa singleton = new Runa( );

   /* A private Constructor prevents any other
    * class from instantiating.
    */
   private Runa() { }

   /* Static 'instance' method */
   public static Runa getInstance( ) {
      return singleton;
   }

   /* Other methods protected by singleton-ness */
   protected static void demoMethod( ) {
      System.out.println("demoMethod for singleton");
   }
}
```

FYI, Singleton ensures that only one object of created for class Runa inside the application. Try to google a bit for more understanding of `Singleton usage` in java

Links:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm

Best of Luck

Comment: why downvote? i think all types of users has the right to get questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score -1):

This most probably refers to a design pattern in software development, called a singleton.

I.e. the class is designed to feature only a single instance, accessible through static means. This isn't a good example of a singleton however, as every field should *only* be accesses through methods. Furthermore, a private constructor might be required to prevent other classes from instantiating the singleton.